# fast custom string splitting

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am writing a custom string split. It will split on a dot(`.`) that is not preceded by an odd number of backslashes (`\`).

```
«string» -> «IEnemerable<string>»
"hello.world" -> "hello", "world"
"abc\.123" -> "abc\.123"
"aoeui\\.dhtns" -> "aoeui\\","dhtns"
```

I would like to know if there is a substring that will reuse the original string (for speed), or is there an existing split that can do this fast?

---

This is what I have but is 2—3 times slower than `input.Split('.')` //where input is a string. (I know it is a (slightly more complex problem, but not that much)

```
    public IEnumerable<string> HandMadeSplit(string input)
    {
        var Result = new LinkedList<string>();
        var word = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var ch in input)
        {
            if (ch == '.')
            {
                Result.AddLast(word.ToString());
                word.Length = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                word.Append(ch);
            }
        }
        Result.AddLast(word.ToString());
        return Result;
    }
```

---

It now uses List instead of LinkedList, and record beginning and end of substring and use string.substring to create the new substrings. This does a lot and is nearly as fast as string.split but I have added my adjustments. (will add code)

Comment: "if there is a substring that will reuse the original string (for speed)" – you can't really implement this if it's not how .NET already behaves.

Comment: will you ever come into the case: `aeiou\.bcde\\.opz` ? or will you only ever have one '.' in your string?

Comment: multiple dots (separators), and occasional escaped dots \. (non separators). Sometime \\ as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop that you show is the right approach if you need performance. (Regex *wouldn't* be).

Switch to an index-based for-loop. Remember the index of the start of the match. Don't append individual chars. Instead, remember the range of characters to copy out and do that with a single `Substring` call per item.

Also, don't use a `LinkedList`. It is slower than a `List` for almost all cases except random-access mutations.

You might also switch from `List` to a normal array that you resize with `Array.Resize`. This results in slightly tedious code (because you have inlined a part of the `List` class into your method) but it cuts out some small overheads.

Next, don't return an `IEnumerable` because that forces the caller through indirection when accessing its items. Return a `List` or an array.

Comment: Changed to List, that does a bit, but also speeds up the client (caller) a lot.

Answer (score 3):

This is the one I eventually settled on. It is not as fast a string.split, but good enough and can be modified, to do what I want.

```
    private IEnumerable<string> HandMadeSplit2b(string input)
    {
        //this one is margenaly better that the second best 2, but makes the resolver (its client much faster), nealy as fast as original.
        var Result = new List<string>();
        var begining = 0;
        var len = input.Length;
        for (var index=0;index<len;index++)
        {
            if (input[index] == '.')
            {
                Result.Add(input.Substring(begining,index-begining));
                begining = index+1;
            }
        }
        Result.Add(input.Substring(begining));
        return Result;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to use `string.Split` for that.

If you need help to implement it, a simple way to solve this is to have loop that scans the string, keeping track of the last place where you found a qualifying dot. When you find a new qualifying dot (or reach the end of the input string), just `yield return` the current substring.

**Edit**: about returning a list or an array vs. using yield

If in your application, the most important thing is the time spent by the caller on iterating the substrings, then you should populate a list or an array and return that, as suggested in the accepted question. I would not use a resizable array while collecting the substrings because this would be slow.

On the other hand, if you care about the overall performance and about memory, and if sometimes the caller doesn't have to iterate over the entire list, you should use `yield return`. When you use `yield return`, you have the advantage that no code at all is executing until the caller has called `MoveNext` (directly or indirectly through a `foreach`). This means that you save the memory for allocating the array/list, and you save the time spent on allocating/resizing/populating the list. You will be spending time almost only on the logic of finding the substrings, and this will be done lazily, that is - only when actually needed because the caller continues to iterate the substrings.

Comment: @richard: Underneath string.Split() will just be looping with overheads. The idea of doing it yourself will remove those overheads and make it faster.