# Scalable Solution for Splitting words in a document?

Tags: c#, .net, string, parsing, search-engine

I have a document in which words are to separated and extracted by a blank space. For that purpose i used the following code.

```
string[] words = s.Split(' ');
```

Now the problem is that i am going to use this code for the parser of a search engine. Because of that there would be hundreds of thousands if not millions of webpages that would be needed to split into words.

Is my concern right that using the above code the process could take very long time or is it unfounded. If it is right any suggestions on an alternative scalable solution would be welcomed.

Comment: You should do the splitting manually. Here's a [related question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13817561/2316200)

Comment: Search term is "tokenization" (and splitting on space is not necessary what you want). Since it is performance question there is no way to answer "is it unfounded" because you have not set any expectations on how fast/scalable result should be - you have to set goals first and than measure solution(s) on data you have. Without any measurements I'd guess the cost of `Split` (even with related GC) will be unnoticeable compared to loading of content.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You are right i should have put forward some quantitative criteria. Anyways since i don't really have an idea on how long it _usually_ takes for the search engines for tokenization i really aren't in a position to give a criteria. I guess i'll go forward with string.split() and will later report back.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own implementation that returns an `IEnumerable<string>` that defers execution.  For example:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> CreateSplitDeferredEnumerable(
    string str,
    char delimiter)
{
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var ch in str) {
        if (ch == delimiter) {
            yield return buffer.ToString();
            buffer.Length = 0;
        } else {
            buffer.Append(ch);
        }
    }

    if (buffer.Length != 0) {
        yield return buffer.ToString();
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<string> SplitDeferred(this string self, char delimiter)
{
    if (self == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("self"); }

    return CreateSplitDeferredEnumerable(self, delimiter);
}
```

Instead of splitting the string in one shot and returning an array of every single sub-string (which will consume a huge amount of memory) you can enumerate the returned enumerable, and the string will be split into pieces on-the-fly.  Assuming that you don't keep the enumerated string objects around after each iteration, they will be immediately eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: This is nice looking code... But I would be very surprised it makes any difference in OP case - take a look at source of any HTML page - there are hardly any long strings, but rather a lot of HTML tags that need to be properly stripped out with something like HtmlAgilityPack...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Even in such a case, the memory footprint will be significantly smaller when processing huge documents -- even if over half of the document is returned as one enumerable element, that's still less memory required at any one moment, and less pressure on the GC.  Considering memory consumption: in the worst case it won't be worse than `String.Split()`, and in the best case it will be *significantly* better.