# What is the most efficient way to convert space-delimited numbers to an array of integers?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, optimization, micro-optimization

My problem is simple: I have a real (not imagined) performance bug in trying to do conversions like

```
"1273 912 84" --> {1273, 912, 84}
```

and so I want to figure out how to do it as fast as possible.

**There are always 3 numbers, the first 2 are always in the range [1, 3000) and the last is always in the range [1, 100000].**

*Background:* I'm working on a HackerRank problem and my solution is timing out on one of the test cases. I read the discussions on the problem and one dude says that the reason everyone is failing the last test case is because of how they parse the gigantic input.

My attempted solution to this performance bug was to create a class like

```
class IntParser
{
    private Dictionary<string, int> _Map = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public IntParser(int n)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
        {
            _Map[i.ToString()] = i;
        }
    }

    public int[] ParseVals(string line)
    {
        return Array.ConvertAll(line.Split(' '), ParseVal);
    }

    public int ParseVal(string s)
    {
        int retval;
        try
        {
            retval = _Map[s]; 
        }
        catch(KeyNotFoundException)
        {
            retval = Int32.Parse(s);
            _Map[s] = retval;
        }
        return retval;
    }
}
```

and initialize it with

```
var parser = new IntParser(100000);
```

and then use it like

```
int[] triplet = parser.ParseVals(Console.ReadLine());
```

Surprisingly, this still isn't efficient enough.

Comment: What is the last test case? You've pretty much defined that the input will only be at most a 16 char string, so how can it be a 'gigantic input'?

Comment: @CharlesMager I mean that the input has 3,000,000+ lines to parse and 80%+ of the runtime is parsing the lines (less than 20% is actually running my algorithm that solves the problem).

Comment: Ah, right, that makes far more sense. Definitely misinterpreted that!

Comment: I would first look at how you're reading the lines; are you sure the perf problem isn't there?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this in O (N) time and O (N) space.
You just have to make a function that iterates over your characters and implement a little state machine. You can be in only 3 states:

1) I am reading a space
2) I am reading a number
3) Reaching the end of list

possible transitions are:
1) Directly read a number
1) From reading space to reading a number
2) From reading a number to reading a space or reaching the end of list

You just have to adapt your code and remember when you enter in state 1). Whenever you exit from state 1) you have to add to a list of numbers what you've read.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without profiling, but several things to keep in mind:

1. `String.Split` generates garbage.
2. Exceptions are expensive in .NET, so better use `TryGetValue` with your cache instead.
3. You can parse probably parse an integer faster than `Int32.Parse` by simply iterating though digits.
4. Dictionary lookup might increase after inserting lots of items compared to the cost of just parsing.

Nevertheless, "3,000,000+ lines" doesn't seem like a huge problem to me, so I am not sure if parsing is your real culprit.

Why not profile? Visual Studio 2015 Community comes bundled with a CPU profiler.

**(Update)**

I tried improving on @Jamiec's answer a bit, by removing `String.Substring` completely and doing all parsing inside the same method, and came up with:

```
static public int[] ParserInPlace(string s)
{
    var result = new int[3];
    var x = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ')
        {
            x++;
            continue;
        }

        result[x] = result[x] * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
    }

    return result;
}
```

On my machine, this seems to be ~2x faster than @Jamiec's solution for random numbers, and ~10x faster than OP's original code (Release mode, x86, Works On My Machine™):

```
RANDOM INPUTS  
ParserBasic:             2068.4759ms  
OP's Parser:             1520.8422ms  
ParserNoSplit:           1300.3933ms  
ParserNoSplitNoIntParse:  322.271ms  
ParserInPlace:            125.0064ms  

SMALLEST INPUT (1 1 1)  
ParserBasic:             1715.9653ms  
OP's Parser:              702.8926ms  
ParserNoSplit:           1006.344ms  
ParserNoSplitNoIntParse:  203.4511ms  
ParserInPlace:             59.2876ms  

LARGEST INPUT (3000 3000 100000)  
ParserBasic:             1971.8206ms  
OP's Parser:              827.6612ms  
ParserNoSplit:           1256.9101ms  
ParserNoSplitNoIntParse:  274.5071ms  
ParserInPlace:            111.802ms
```

If you need to parse one line at a time, then perhaps you don't need to allocate the same `int[] result` array in each iteration (but you do need to set it to zero), so you might reduce garbage even further this way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient I can come up with is to just not use `String.Split` or `int.Parse` at all.

I compared 4 different ways

1. Using a basic `String.Split`
2. Using Your `IntParser`
3. Using a variation on [this fast string split answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810664/fast-custom-string-splitting)
4. Adding @CharlesMager's code for parsing an integer to 3.

Here's how I did the comparisons.

I created 3,000,000 strings using this algorythm to match your input

```
static string CreateExampleString()
{
    return String.Join(" ", new[] { rnd.Next(1, 3000), rnd.Next(1, 3000), rnd.Next(1, 100000) });
}
```

I created a benchmarking tester

```
static TimeSpan Test(Func<string,int[]> parser, List<string> inputs)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    foreach (var input in inputs)
        parser(input);
    sw.Stop();

    return sw.Elapsed;
}
```

And then I defined the 4 test cases, the first was

```
static int[] ParserBasic(string input)
{
    return input.Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
}
```

The second was just your `IntParser` as I already said, the third was

```
static public int[] ParserNoSplit(string s)
{
    int[] result = new int[3];
    int x = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for(var i=0;i<s.Length;i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == ' ')
        {
            result[x++] = int.Parse(s.Substring(b, i - b));
            b = i + 1;
        }
    }
    result[x] = int.Parse(s.Substring(b));
    return result;
}
```

Finally, I took the above and replaced the `int.Parse` with the code for the parsing in @CharlesMager answer, and got the best results yet!

```
static public int[] ParserNoSplitNoIntParse(string s)
{
    int[] result = new int[3];
    int x = 0;
    int b = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ')
        {
            result[x++] = ParseVal(s.Substring(b, i - b));
            b = i + 1;
        }
    }
    result[x] = ParseVal(s.Substring(b));
    return result;
}

static int ParseVal(string s)
{
    var result = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        result = result * 10 + (s[i] - '0');
    }

    return result;
}
```

The actual test code was

```
var allStrings = Enumerable.Range(0, 3000000).Select(x => CreateExampleString()).ToList();
var result1 = Test(ParserBasic, allStrings);
Console.WriteLine($"Result1: {result1.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

var result2 = Test(parser.ParseVals, allStrings);
Console.WriteLine($"Result2: {result2.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

var result3 = Test(ParserNoSplit, allStrings);
Console.WriteLine($"Result3: {result3.TotalMilliseconds}ms");

var result4 = Test(ParserNoSplitNoIntParse, allStrings);
Console.WriteLine($"Result4: {result4.TotalMilliseconds}ms");
```

The result of running the same 3 million inputs through each was as follows:

> Result1: 2491ms
>   Result2: 2132ms
>   Result3: 1579ms
>   Result4: 861ms

Which is better, for sure. It can probably be improved on more but avoiding `String.Split` improves the overall performance.

Comment: Having just played with this a bit myself, you can also avoid the allocation of `Substring` by just passing `s` and the bounds into `ParseVal`. On my machine that gets you from 188ms to 66ms for 3m.

Comment: Here's a cut down version of my code (You cant run 3million in rextester) http://rextester.com/WFJR71269 so anyone else can have a play to improve it more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (be sure to use Try Catch in case your string does not have a convertible string inside it:

```
    string myString = "1234 321 145";
    int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(myString.Split(' '), int.Parse);
```

Edit here:
I made a test to see the time spent:

```
    List<String> list = new List<String>();
    Random rnd = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
        list.Add(String.Join(" ", new[] { rnd.Next(1, 3000), rnd.Next(1, 3000), rnd.Next(1, 100000) }));
    }
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3000; i++) {
        int[] myInts = Array.ConvertAll(list[i].Split(' '), int.Parse);
    }

    sw.Stop();

    MessageBox.Show(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```

The result was: 00:00:00.0016167

Comment: Nope, that's what I did originally and am trying to improve on.

Answer (score 0):

I get 43% faster (per dotTrace) with this implementation:

```
public int ParseVal(string s)
{
    var result = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        result = result*10 + (s[i] - '0');
    }

    return result;
}
```

The bulk of the time (70%) is now in `String.Split` - a quick google comes up with things [like this](http://dejan-pelzel.com/post/109194509740/c-high-performance-net-string-split) that might help.